# I need to determine the load weight capacity for 2" x 12" pine board laid flat resting on two points

Tags: wood, load-bearing, shelf

Boards are used as shelf decking. Each end rests on beams that have a 7/8" lip. We use 2x8", 2x10", and 2x12" pine boards of approximately 40" in length. I have not been able to locate a formula for pine laid flat. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be helpful. Diagram below.

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure where to find it, but maybe look for load bearing of steps.  With 1 1/2 thick wood, a 2x, would feel quite safe walking and maybe taking small jumps on it at 40 inch spans.  So maybe a plus 200 pound standing/dead load.

Comment: I meant a spread out load, not one that is at a point or very small area.

Comment: if you have a formula, you just need to use the right numbers for it being "flat" rather than the assumed vertical loading. this one is useful in practice for shelving, since sag becomes objectionable well before breaking: https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/  or

Comment: Here's one where you can flip the dimensions around to make it flat, for uniform loading, with "easy input" species data. Same place also has various point loading setups but you have to input the lumber data. http://www.timbertoolbox.com/Calcs/ddsimplebeam.html

Comment: Those boards should be able to hold **a lot**. Typical shelving for books (which are quite a heavy load) is 3/4" or 1", and you've got 1-1/2"

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick help.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend checking out the [Sagulator](https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/).

You can use it to determine approximate load bearing capacity of almost any wood type for any span and weight. The Sagulator will report the expected deflection under a given load amount and type and will report whether it's considered acceptable or not. Of course, final judgement is up to you.

Do bear in mind that wood is a *natural* product and that no two boards will be exactly the same. I'd imagine that these are somewhat conservative numbers, but I haven't read all the fine print at their site to be sure of that.

You indicate 2" x 10" (or 12"). When plugging your numbers into the Sagulator, be sure to specify 1.5" by 9.5" or 11.25" if you're using standard dimensional framing lumber since that's sold as a "nominal" 2x10 or 2x12. You'll want the calculations to be based on *actual* lumber sizes.

Comment: Sagulator is nice except for its traffic light judgments.  As you say ... conservative.  The bar seems to be "imperceptible sag" which is often desirable but often unnecessary.

Comment: I'll be certain to use the addressed down size of the wood. Thanks for the top.